# Add CSS/SCSS property to main component for child component's element (h1) while using router-outlet in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, router-outlet

I have a major component 'Dashboard with following Code'

```
  ...
  <div class="col-8 container-right">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

And with the following SCSS:

```
.container-right{
    padding:2.5rem 0rem;

}

router-outlet h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
```

the `router-outlet h1` Not working.

I have another component 'Trips' with following HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1 *ngIf="currentLoc == 'myPlanners'; else friendPlannerHead">My Trips</h1>
...
```

Other components are also in similar fashion. Now I want to add `margin-botton:1rem` to `h1` tag from the **Dashboard Component**. Can anyone share the possible solutions?

Comment: First thing, when angular renders a view by matching the route, it does render the component after the `router-outlet` html tag. So `router-outlet h1` tag would never match it (even though the component has `Encapsulation.None` is set). Better I can suggest move common CSS to styles.scss (global level) to themefy application

Answer (score 0):

To `dashboard.component.css` add style. It's encapuslated so only `dashboard.component` will be affected.

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

You can not style `router-outlet`, but the router outlet will render `<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>` which's `<h1>` could be targeted. In `styles.css` global stylesheet add:

```css
app-dashboard > h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```